# Unreal engine 5 render crash

Tags: unreal-engine5

I'm New to Unreal and i was starting my first project. when i render the project crash occur and i got this error

Assertion failed: Desc.GetSize() > 0
[File:D:\build++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\RenderCore\Private\RenderGraphValidation.cpp] [Line: 285] Creating buffer 'GPUScene.InstanceSceneData' is zero bytes in size.

UnrealEditor_RenderCore
UnrealEditor_RenderCore
UnrealEditor_RenderCore
UnrealEditor_Renderer
UnrealEditor_Renderer
UnrealEditor_Renderer
UnrealEditor_Renderer
UnrealEditor_Renderer
UnrealEditor_Renderer
UnrealEditor_Renderer
UnrealEditor_Renderer
UnrealEditor_Core
UnrealEditor_Core
UnrealEditor_RenderCore
UnrealEditor_RenderCore
UnrealEditor_Core
UnrealEditor_Core
kernel32
ntdll

I'm new and don't know anything, can anybody help me please?

my desktop is
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 7900X
GPU: NVDIA Geforce RTX 4070ti
AMD Radeon(TM) RGraphincs

mainboard: Gigabyte Technology Co. B650M AORUS ELITE

Ram: TEAMGROUP inc, UD5-4800 DDR5 64G